# stage.toJSON() in kinetic js HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, kineticjs

you can refer to this example

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-load-complex-stage-with-kineticjs/

M trying to achive the same thing ,it’s like a studio where user has the option of saving and reloading the canvas..
But it involves images..
For Static images I’m using the same approach as in the above mentioned example.
but there are a lot of dynamic images that I’m placing inside the canvas through an ajax call..
and the id by which the images get fetched are different for different images
but there is no way of knowing the number of images
So How can I add the same function for a new image and make it universal for all the images..
Cause the number of images is dynamic so I can't add function for images just like that without knowing..
Please help..
Hope I’m able to explain myself

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/sKymY/2/

to make this work you have to add a custon attribute called src with the image address and give them the name image (or whatever you choose).